# Finite Crossing

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I was curious about the following question:

Let $\{B_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $\mu, a\in\Re$ be arbitrarily given real numbers. Let $L=\{\tau\in\Re_+\,|\,X_\tau=a\}$, where (assume that $\mu\ne 0$) 
$$X_t\equiv \mu t+B_t.$$ 
Then is it true that for every $T\in\Re_+$, the set $[0,T]\cap L$ is almost surely finite?

By intuition, I think the answer should be yes, but I cannot figure out a convincing logic. Would anyone give me some hint or reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The set of zeros of Brownian motion is a a.s. a perfect set (closed and has no isolated points).

In particular, since $B_0=0$, for the choice $a=0$,  each of the sets $[0,T]\cap L$ is a.s. uncountable.

Now for $a\ne 0$, on the event $\{\tau_a \le T\}$, where $\tau_a$ is hitting time of $a$, the same conclusion holds (note that the probability that $\tau_a = T$ is zero). For each $T$ this event has probability less than $1$, but increasing  $1$ as $T\to\infty$ because of recurrence.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks! But what if we consider the diffusion process $X_t=\mu t+B_t$, where $\mu\in \Re$ is a non-zero drift. For such a stochastic process we define $L=\{\tau\in \Re\,|\, X_\tau=a\}$. Then is it true that $L\cap [0,T]$ is almost surely finite for all $T\ge 0$?

Comment: By Girsanov, the distribution of drifted BM is equivalent  with  the distribution of  standard BM on any *finite* interval $[0,T]$. Therefore any event in ${\cal F}_t$ which has probability zero/one in one of them has probability zero/one in the other.